# Nodejs, Express - Get content from a div or a textArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm developing a web app with NodeJs and Express on the server side, angular on the client side. I have a simple HTML page where there is a div with this content:

```
<div id="test"> {{angularOutput}} </div>
```

In this div, I decided to output a particular string.

EDIT: In my HTML page there's also a form and a POST request to the server side. Till now I sent single parameters to server side. Now I want to send the whole content of the div above.

Then, what I want to do is to **take the content of this div and give it to the server side**. I have looked for some solutions but without finding one. Finally I was thinking about install jquery as dependency but before I want to know if there's a better solution directly from express.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There's no way to access the clientside from the serverside directly, you have to send the data with a POST or GET request, and that can be done with ajax as well, or use sockets.

Comment: Sorry i've forgotten that in my code there's a form that sends data with a POST. I'll edit the topic. Till now i've used the "req.body.someField" to send input to the server side. Now I want to send the whole content of a div instead of single fields.